# Android edittext color change for @mentions and #hashtags while typing

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `edittext` and when the user types in it the color of **@mentions** and **#hashtags** should change. I have used `textwatcher` but it is laggy and it misses out some characters while typing. I would love to hear about alternatives.

This is my code:

```
var previousString = ""
        override fun initTextAreaView() {
            if(twitterAvailable && twitterIsEnabled) CHARLIMIT = 280
            if(!twitterIsEnabled && linkedInAvailable && linkedInIsEnabled) CHARLIMIT = 700
            charcount.text = CHARLIMIT.toString()
            content.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    if(s.toString()!=previousString)checkMentionsAndHashtags(s.toString())

                }
            })
        }

        var textSpanList: ArrayList<TextSpan> = ArrayList()
        private fun checkMentionsAndHashtags(s: String) {
            previousString = s
            textSpanList = ArrayList()
            val words = s.split(" ")
            for(word in words){
                if(word.length>0) {
                    if (word[0] == '@' || word[0] == '#') {
                        val n = s.lastIndexOf(word)
                        textSpanList.add(TextSpan(n, (n+word.length)))
                    }
                }
            }
            changeTextColor(s, SpannableStringBuilder(s))
        }

        private fun changeTextColor(s: String = "", str: SpannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder("")) {
            Log.d("TEXTSPANS", textSpanList.toString())
            if(textSpanList.size>0){
                for(span in textSpanList) {
                    str.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)), span.startPos, span.endPos, 0)
                }
            }
            val cursorPos = content.selectionEnd
            content.text = str
            content.setSelection(cursorPos)
        }
```

Comment: i found one [library](https://github.com/tylersuehr7/social-text-view).this may help you

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati it didnt work with edittext. I am dealing with cursor positions too, so i need something to work with edittext. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: See my updated post it will help you.. its works fine to me..

Comment: See my solution in kotlin for hashtag similarly you can do for mention; https://stackoverflow.com/a/57481803/2522797

Answer (score 0):

you have to try like this

```
  lateinit var content:EditText
    private var intCount = 0
    private var initialStringLength = 0
    private var strText = ""

    private fun initTextAreaView() {
        content= findViewById(R.id.testText)
        content.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                val typedString = s.toString()
                val stringArrayObj = typedString.split(" ".toRegex()).dropLastWhile({ it.isEmpty() }).toTypedArray()
                var cnt = 0
                if (typedString.length != initialStringLength && typedString.length != 0) {
                    if (typedString.substring(typedString.length - 1) != " ") {
                        initialStringLength = typedString.length
                        cnt = intCount
                        for (i in stringArrayObj.indices)
                            if (stringArrayObj[i].get(0) == '#' || stringArrayObj[i].get(0) == '@') {
                                 strText = strText + " " + "<font color='#EE0000'>" + stringArrayObj[i] + "</font>"
                            }
                            else
                                strText = strText + " " + stringArrayObj[i]
                    }
                    if (intCount == cnt) {
                        intCount = stringArrayObj.size
                        content.setText(Html.fromHtml(strText))
                        content.setSelection(content.getText().toString().length)
                    }
                } else {
                    strText = ""
                }

            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: can you try with my sample input?